# Return multiple data frames from function R

Tags: r

I am trying to put together a function that will loop thru a given data frame in blocks and return a new data frame containing stuff calculated from the original. The length of x will be different each time and the actual problem will have more loops in the function. New-ish to R and have not been able to find anything helpful (I don't think using a list will help)

```
func<-function(x){
    tmp # need to declare this here?
    for (i in 1:dim(x)[1]){
        tmp[i]<-ave(x[i,]) # add things to it
    }
    return(tmp)
 }
 df<-cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
 means<-func(df)
```

This code does not work but I hope it gets across what I want to do. thanks!

Comment: Your question is not very clear (to me). Your title suggests you want to know how to write a function that returns multiple data frames, but your code only attempts to return one data frame. And I don't understand the logic of your looping strategy at all. Perhaps if you explained what you're actually doing in more detail...?

Comment: couple things.  `dim(x)[1]` can be `nrow(x)`.  You're wanting to find the mean of each row?  `apply(x,1,mean)` will do that... but take a look at [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) its great at splitting data.frames and processing each piece.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want to loop through each row of `df` and return a data frame with the calculated values?

You may want to look in to the `apply` function:

```
df <- cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
# apply(df,1,FUN) does FUN(df[i,])
# e.g. mean of each row:
apply(df,1,mean)
```

For more complicated looping like performing some operation on a per-factor basis, I strongly recommend package `plyr`, and function `ddply` within. Quick example:

```
df <- data.frame( gender=c('M','M','F','F'), height=c(183,176,157,168) )
# find mean height *per gender*
ddply(df,.(gender), function(x) c(height=mean(x$height)))
# returns:
  gender height
1      F  162.5
2      M  179.5
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. What I want to do (but did not explain in the original question bc I was hoping I could get pointed in the right direction without it) pull out blocks of a df based on the values of one of its column.

Comment: Its a sorted column where I will grab all the rows where its 0-1 do a calc, 1-2, 2-3 and so on. There could be a different number of blocks each time and they will all be different lengths. So its complicated and I just need a better idea where to look, I can start with this package. (sorry for the double comment, new here)

Comment: In that case I think the plyr package will do exactly what you want -- it splits your dataframe into blocks based on a column and then you can write the function that processes each block. You'll just have to make a separate column that says what interval each row is in (ie sorts each row into the groups 0-1, 1-2, ..) and then use `ddply`.

Comment: Awesome. I will see what I can cook up. Thanks!